# how to render template based on condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, local-storage, conditional-statements, webapp2

How to render a template based on javascript conditional statement i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(localStorage.getItem("signedIn")=="True"){
        {% include 'shared/headers/simple-header.html' %}
    }else{
        {% include 'shared/headers/loggedin-header.html' %}
    }
</script>
```

Above code does not work and it gives me errors in javascript console

what is the best practice, thanks in advance.

Comment: I also have tried with document.write function of javascript but result remains the same!

Comment: the template happens in the server side. Javascript happens in the client side. This is why it does not work.

Comment: no, webapp2 with google app engine - python

Comment: The `{% %}` template magic executes before the javascript.  So, you are essentially injecting html code into your javascript.

Comment: yes, @GAEfan is spot on. The {%} builds the page and the javascript only fires after the page is built. I don't think you can access localStorage data until after the page is rendered.

Comment: yes you are right, I got it.

Answer (score 2):

The `{% %}` template magic executes before the javascript. So, you are essentially injecting html code into your javascript.  `{% %}` is done on the server (server side), and sent to the template.  Javascript is done after the template is received, in the browser (client side).

This is a bit hacky, but gets around the timing issue:

```
<div id="simpleHeader" style="display:none;">
    {% include 'shared/headers/simple-header.html' %}
</div>
<div id="loggedInHeader" style="display:none;">
    {% include 'shared/headers/loggedin-header.html' %}
</div>

<script>
    if(localStorage.getItem("signedIn")=="True"){  // if string "True", no quotes if Boolean True
        document.getElementById("loggedInHeader").style.display = "block";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("simpleHeader").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

Would be better to check login on the server side.

Comment: this is never coming into ture part of the condition, but when I  check the value of "signedIn" by making an alert it say: True

Comment: Perhaps it is a boolean, and not a string: `if(localStorage.getItem("signedIn")==True){`

Comment: Sorry I got it actually it was ' True' in my local storage.